# Integration by parts with Hilbert transform

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is there a good integration by parts formula to compute
$$\int_{0}^\infty f \  H (f') dx,$$
where $H$ denotes the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) and $f$ is a smooth function?

Comment: are you sure you want the integral fron 0 to $\infty$, not from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Yes, I'd like to compute the integral from 0.

Comment: We have $H f' = (-\Delta)^{1/2} f$, so if $f$ is smooth and supported in $(0,\infty)$, the integral should be equal to $\int_0^\infty f (-\Delta)^{1/2} f = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f (-\Delta)^{1/2} f = \int_{-\infty}^\infty ((-\Delta)^{1/4} f)^2$. I doubt this is what you are looking for, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this? (with integration from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ to arrive at a nicely symmetric answer):
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f \  H (f') dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\text{P.V.}\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)f'(y)}{x-y}\,dxdy$$
$$\qquad=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)f'(y)\frac{d}{dx}\log|x-y|\,dxdy$$
$$\qquad=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)f'(y)\log|x-y|\,dxdy.$$
Alternatively, with both integrals from $0$ to $\infty$,
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\text{P.V.}\,\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty \frac{f(x)f'(y)}{x-y}\,dxdy$$
$$\qquad=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty f(x)f'(y)\frac{d}{dx}\log|x-y|\,dxdy$$
$$\qquad=-\frac{1}{\pi}f(0)\int_{0}^\infty f'(y)\log y\,dy-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty f'(x)f'(y)\log|x-y|\,dxdy.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I actually wanted the integral from 0 to $\infty$ (in which case we also define the Hilbert transform with the integral $pv \int_0^\infty......$. Is there anything we can do in this case?

Comment: Thank you very much! That looks great. Can this be generalized if we replace $f'$ with $f^{(k)}$ ($k$-th derivative of $f$)?

Comment: I don't think it's clear that the step from the first to the second line is justified. The principal value has disappeared. (It is true that $PV(1/x)=(\log |x|)'$, but this is in distributional sense, not as functions.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling --- since we are integrating, the distributional equality $\text{PV}(1/x)=d/dx \log |x|$ should hold for smooth $f(x)$, you don't agree?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Also, could you add some detail on the last identity (from second to third line) of the half-line case? How do you get the expression in line 3 from integrating by parts in line 2?

Comment: @Jun --- I may be missing something, but the step from line 2 to line 3 is just the definition of integration by parts over $x$: the first term with $f(0)$ is the boundary term at $x=0$, the second term is the remaining integral [the boundary term at $x=\infty$ is assumed to vanish for a decaying $f(x)$]

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I'm not sure we can justify the step in this way. Maybe a better way to put my comment is as follows: if we just evaluate $d/dx \log |x-y| = 1/(x-y)$ in the second line, we're back in the first line, but the PV has disappeared, and just dropping it looks a bit fishy to me. (I think your formula is probably fine, but the derivation could be made more waterproof.)

Comment: By the way, we could also use Fourier transforms: since $\widehat{Hf}=i\textrm{sgn}(k)\widehat{f}$ and $\widehat{f'}=-ik\widehat{f}$ (ignoring $\pm 2\pi$'s, which depend on your conventions anyway), we have $\int f Hf' = \int |k| \widehat{f}(-k)\widehat{f}(k)$, which is probably the same as your formula, but the identification also runs into some issues: $\log |x|\, \widehat{}$ can't just be $1/|k|$, which we get formally, since this isn't locally integrable ...

Comment: (cont'd) The regularization is a bit messy: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-log-x-xs-and-logx